# Adding an onclick event to a new html element only working on the last element

Tags: javascript, html

The problem is that when I create page number buttons at the bottom of the page the onclick only ever works with the last element created.

Here is what the page buttons look like:

[image: Here is what the page buttons look like]

```
    for(var i = 0; i < numberOfPages; i++) {
        if(Math.floor((((startIndex + 1) / 10) + 1)) == (i + 1)) {
            var newElement = document.createElement("u");
            document.getElementById("imagesNav").appendChild(newElement);
            newElement.id = "imagesNavU";
            var newElement = document.createElement("a");
            document.getElementById("imagesNavU").appendChild(newElement);
            var str = "page" + (i + 1);
            newElement.innerHTML = i + 1;
            newElement.onclick=function(){currentPageNumber(str);};
        } else {
            var newElement = document.createElement("a");
            document.getElementById("imagesNav").appendChild(newElement);
            var str = "page" + (i + 1);
            newElement.innerHTML = i + 1;
            newElement.onclick=function(){currentPageNumber(str);};         
        }
        if(i + 1 != numberOfPages) {
            document.getElementById("imagesNav").innerHTML += "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        }
    }
}
```

The first if statement just puts underline tags on if that element is the current page.

Edit:  The problem has been solved.  Thank you to everyone for their help!

Comment: Would be much easier to help if you first included the code `currentPageNumber()` function.

Comment: @etherealite That function is irrelevant, the problem is that all the closures are using the same `str` variable.

Comment: @Barmar Would the function still be called though?  The function is only ever called with the last button.

Comment: I think you're confused about what's going wrong. The function is called for all the links, but they all call it with the same `str` argument, which comes from the last iteration of the loop.

Comment: An unrelated problem is that you seem to be creating multiple elements with `id=imagesNavU`, every time the `if` succeeds. IDs should be unique. I'm not sure why you need that ID, since you have the new `<u>` element in a variable and you could just use that variable to append the child (or course, you'll need to use a different variable name for the `<a>` element).

Comment: @Barmar That may be true, but I put a breakpoint in the function the onclick calls and the breakpoint is only ever triggered by the last element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this part of the loop:

```
    if(i + 1 != numberOfPages) {
        document.getElementById("imagesNav").innerHTML += "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    }
```

This is re-parsing all the HTML in the `imagesNav` element. This creates new `<a>` elements, which don't have the `onclick` bindings that the previous ones had.

Instead, you can append a `<span>` element containing the spaces.

```js
var numberOfPages = 3;
var startIndex = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < numberOfPages; i++) {
  if (Math.floor((((startIndex + 1) / 10) + 1)) == (i + 1)) {
    var newElement = document.createElement("u");
    document.getElementById("imagesNav").appendChild(newElement);
    newElement.id = "imagesNavU";
    var newElement = document.createElement("a");
    document.getElementById("imagesNavU").appendChild(newElement);
    var str = "page" + (i + 1);
    newElement.innerHTML = i + 1;
    newElement.onclick = function() {
      currentPageNumber(str);
    };
  } else {
    var newElement = document.createElement("a");
    document.getElementById("imagesNav").appendChild(newElement);
    var str = "page" + (i + 1);
    newElement.innerHTML = i + 1;
    newElement.onclick = function() {
      currentPageNumber(str);
    };
  }
  if (i + 1 != numberOfPages) {
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerHTML = '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
    document.getElementById("imagesNav").appendChild(span);
  }
}

function currentPageNumber(str) {
  alert(str);
}
```

```html
<div id="imagesNav">

</div>
```

Another way to do it is with [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML), which adds HTML to an element without re-parsing what's already in it.

```
    document.getElementById("imagesNav").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '&nbsp;&nbsp;');
```

You should also see [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example?lq=1) because the way you're using the `str` variable, all the click handlers will use the value from the last iteration of the loop.

Comment: note that clicks work but all return `Page3`. Correct form is `function currentPageNumber(str) { return function(){alert(str);}}` and `newElement.onclick = currentPageNumber(str);`

Comment: @AlexKudryashev That's the problem I pointed out in the last paragraph of the answer.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev That's what I originally thought his whole problem was, so I closed the question as a duplicate. Then I saw the other problem, so I reopened it, and just added the link as additional information, since it's not directly related to the question he asked.

Comment: @Barmer You are the best!  This solved my problem.  You guys are great!